# How to find out the initiator of a script in unix

Tags: source

I am wondering if there is a way to find out how a file execution was initiated.

For example, consider the following files:

`~/foo.sh`

```
echo "Hello from foo.sh"
# print the name of the initiator/parent of this execution
```

`~/bar.sh`

```
source ~/foo.sh
```

`~/baz.sh`

```
. ~/foo.sh
```

---

When I execute

`sh ~/bar.sh` or `.~/bar.sh`, `~/foo.sh` should print `~/bar.sh`

`sh ~/baz.sh` or `.~/baz.sh`, `~/foo.sh` should print `~/baz.sh`

---

I am trying to be generic but it could be specific to `bash` or `zsh`.

Comment: Have you tried `$0`?

Comment: Please edit to make it clear what you are trying to do. I have far too many interpretations of this to give a useful answer, that is not a large chunk of a manual.

Comment: Hi @roaima I have updated the question, could you take another look? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a `bash` solution (for scripts with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, or run with `bash script...`).

Set up the example (two scripts, `a.sh` and `b.sh`):

```
cat >a.sh <<'x' && chmod a+x a.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo This is a.sh
source b.sh
echo End a.sh
x

cat >b.sh <<'x' && chmod a+x b.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo This is b.sh
echo "BASH_SOURCE=(${BASH_SOURCE[@]}) and we are '${BASH_SOURCE[0]}' called by '${BASH_SOURCE[1]}'"
echo End b.sh
x
```

Now run the code and review the output:

```
./a.sh
This is a.sh
This is b.sh
BASH_SOURCE=(b.sh ./a.sh) and we are 'b.sh' called by './a.sh'
End b.sh
End a.sh
```

As you can see, in a `source`d file the caller can be identified with `"${BASH_SOURCE[1]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible with the `bash` shell. `source` can supply an argument to the file there.

That means you could construct foo.sh as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello from $1"
```

and bar.sh as

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/Codes/tests/foo.sh '~/bar.sh'
```

finally baz.sh would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/Codes/tests/foo.sh '~/baz.sh'
```

If you care about *how* the script was invoked, then you could also write foo.sh as

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello from $0"
```

and bar.sh as

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/Codes/tests/foo.sh
```

This will give `Hello from ./bar.sh` if you invoke it from the scripts directory. If you invoke it from your home you will get `Hello from ~/bar.sh`

Comment: Thank you Max1! Is there any other way to find out how a script is getting invoked?

Comment: OP says `sh` not `bash`, so you cannot assume `source` permits a second argument. @sarbbottam if you are allowing `bash` extensions please update your question to say so.

Comment: I always use `.sh` as a file extension for my `bash` scripts. I wouldn't deduce from that, that its supposed to be `sh` shell.

Comment: Max1, the OP in their question shows `sh a.sh`, which is clearly `sh` rather than `bash` (the "extension" is irrelevant - it's the command that's vital here).

Comment: Sorry, your right I overlooked that.

Comment: Hi Max1, roaima I have updated the question, could you take another look? Thank you!